# Finding covariance structure for Bernoulli GLMM (Random Intercept)

Tags: covariance, glmm, bernoulli-distribution

How does one find the covariance structure theoretically for a Bernoulli GLM?

For Normal LMMs ($y_{ik} = x_i^T\beta + \epsilon_i + u_k$) it's quite straight forward. For observations within the same group we can calculate
$$ cov(y_{ik},y_{jk}) = cov(x_i^T\beta + \epsilon_i + u_k, x_j^T\beta + \epsilon_j + u_k) = cov(\epsilon_i + u_k, \epsilon_j + u_k) \\ = cov(\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j) + cov(\epsilon_i , u_k) + cov(u_k, \epsilon_j) + cov(u_k,u_k)  = \sigma_u^2$$

And similarly for observations of different groups we can find that the covariance is 0.
But how does one calculates it for a Bernoulli GLM? Say, with the logit link function?

$$ logit(\mu_{ik})=x_i^T\beta + u_k \Rightarrow \mu_{ik} = \sigma(x_i^T\beta + u_k)$$

Is there anyway to calculate $cov(y_{ik},y_{jk})$? Does adding a random intercept to the link function even affects the covariance structure, or do we also have to add an extra assumption about the structure of the covariance?